# Boost C regex - how to return all matches

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have a string `"SolutionAN  ANANANA SolutionBNabcabcSolutionX"` and I want to return all string which start with `Solution` and end just before sub string `Solution`.

While using `boost::regex` I am unable to make regular expression for it.

I want to get `SolutionAN  ANANANA`,  `SolutionBNababc` and `SolutionX` as output. I am new to regex in boost, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
(?s)Solution.*?(?=Solution|$)
```

`.*?` would match 0 to many characters **lazily** i.e it eats as less as possible.
Without `?` it would become greedy and eat as much as possible.

`x(?=yz)` is a lookahead which matches x only if it is followed by yz

`$` is the end of string

---

`.` by default won't match newline character..You should use `(?s)` modifier within regex or use `mod_s` option which causes `.` to match newline character

Comment: I think this regex is not able to pass while string is containing new line character like input : Solution Avc \n mn Solutionxy then it is giving output as Solution Avc and Solutionxy while I want output as Solution Avc \n mn and Solutionxy

Comment: Can you please tell how to use match_no_dot_null option ?

Comment: I dont think It is resolving the issue :/

Comment: @AmitPandey You can try this regex `Solution(.|[\n\r])*?(?=Solution|$)` ..should work

Comment: NO It is still not resolving the issue If you say I can give code to you.

Comment: @AmitPandey [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/libs/regex/doc/syntax_option_type.html) it says to use `boost::regex::mod_s` as option

Comment: @AmitPandey SO the option should be something like `boost::regex::perl|boost::regex::mod_s`

Comment: I am using boost in C++, how should I incorporate it with C++ ?

Comment: @AmitPandey you should [refer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/libs/regex/doc/syntax_option_type.html) the site for more information

Comment: Thanks I will refer to that